# How to use `term` role to reference math equations in glossory in sphinx-doc

Tags: python-sphinx

Sphinx-doc supports [term role](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/roles.html#role-term) to work with [glossary directive](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/directives.html#glossary). Suppose inside glossary, I have a math formula as a key like below

```
:math:`{[n] \choose k}`
  Set of :math:`k`-subsets of :math:`[n]`
```

I tried to reference it via term role using

```
:term:`{[n] \choose k}`
```

But, when I build the doc, I hit the following warning message

> WARNING: term not in glossary: {[n] choose k}

How can I reference math formula key using term role in sphinx-doc? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I have is to define a meaningful replacement string for the equation and then use that replacement string in the glossary:

```
.. |n-choose-k| replace:: :math:`{[n] \choose k}`

.. glossary::

   |n-choose-k|
      Set of :math:`k`-subsets of :math:`[n]`

Reference the term above :term:`like this <n-choose-k>`
```

[see output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaQKs.png)

You can have any anchor text for the link with the term, but I don't think it's possible to place a math formula there.